# BigQuery dataset access when specialGroup member

Tags: google-bigquery, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

In BigQuery you can configure the *access* at a dataset-level.

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets):

> BigQuery adds default dataset access for the following entities: access.specialGroup: projectReaders; access.role: READER; access.specialGroup: projectWriters; access.role: WRITER; access.specialGroup: projectOwners; access.role: OWNER; access.userByEmail: [dataset creator email]; access.role: OWNER;

However, **I haven't been able to find a deterministic equivalence of such `specialGroup` values to the project's policy roles**.

The referenced documentation doesn't shed a lot of light in this aspect:

> A special group to grant access to. Possible values include: projectOwners: Owners of the enclosing project. projectReaders: Readers of the enclosing project. projectWriters: Writers of the enclosing project. allAuthenticatedUsers: All authenticated BigQuery users. Maps to similarly-named IAM members.

My understanding is that (please, correct me if I'm wrong) these values would identify all *members* within the project's policy whose bound role is one of the following:

- `projectOwners` -> `roles/bigquery.dataOwner` (and/or `roles/owner`?)
- `projectWriters` -> `roles/bigquery.dataEditor` (and/or `roles/editor`?)
- `projectReaders` -> `roles/bigquery.dataViewer` (and/or `roles/viewer`?)

But at the end, those *roles* aren't more than a *set* of *permissions*, right? So, what happens if there's a *custom* role which contains the same subset of *permissions* as `bigquery.dataViewer`? Would users bound to this role also be able to access the datasets?

So, my question would be:

**Does `specialGroup`'s values have a deterministic equivalent to the project's roles and if so, what is it?**

The final goal is determine exactly who can access a dataset, either configured directly within dataset's access or inherited via project's policies.

Answer (score 0):

The "specialGroup" possible values, are analog to the similarly named [primitive roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control-primitive-roles?hl=en_US#primitive_roles_for_projects) for projects:

- projectOwners -> Project Owners
- projectWriters -> Project Editors
- projectReaders -> Project Viewers

If you try the [get dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/get) API method in a dataset, by default, the "access" object you'll get in the response will be like:

```js
"access": [
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "specialGroup": "projectWriters"
    },
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "specialGroup": "projectOwners"
    },
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "userByEmail": "userWhoCreatedTheDataset@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "role": "READER",
      "specialGroup": "projectReaders"
    }
  ]
```

The "role" possible values makes reference to the permission granted over that specific dataset, which, by default, are granted to the analog project-level roles (the "specialGroups" possible values). The dataset creator also gets granted a dataset OWNER access, although not by a specialGroup, but by a userByEmail value. However, if the user who created the dataset was also the project owner, he would also belong to the projectOwners specialGroup.

Regarding the custom roles, you're right, a role is a set of permissions, if you create a custom role with exactly the same permissions as bigquery.dataViewer, and then you grant, for example, a service account that custom role, it would have the same permissions as if was granted the bigquery.dataViewer role.